# How to remove symbol and space from a string in JavaScript

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, regular-expressions

I have a string called myValue.

```
let myValue= 'Premium+-+Mobile+Plan'
```

And I need the output as `Premium Mobile Plan`

I tried to use replace method.

```
let myValue= 'Premium+-+Mobile+Plan' 
console.log(myValue); // Premium+-+Mobile+Plan 

let newValue = myValue.replace(/[+-]/g, ' ');
console.log(newValue ); // Premium   Mobile Plan
```

I am getting an extra space between Premium and Mobile.
How to remove the extra space.

Comment: Not sure, why "-" is there. It is what it is. This value is coming from a 3rd party system. We are consuming it. This "Premium+-+Mobile+Plan" is a whole string .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To replace multiple spaces with a single space , you can try below regex :

```
/  +/g
```

Here, the Regex detects 1 or more space(s) throughout the string.

We need to use the regex in the `replace` method as shown below:

```
let myValue= 'Premium+-+Mobile+Plan' 
console.log(myValue); // Premium+-+Mobile+Plan 

let newValue = myValue.replace(/[+-]/g, ' ').replace(/  +/g, ' ');
console.log(newValue ); // Premium Mobile Plan
```

Comment: Got it, thanks @Rohit for your inputs. Got the desired output. Can we have some other approach rather using chaining of replace method.

Comment: There might be a way to combine them but chaining looks better for readability.

Comment: @ArchitaPatnaik `/ |\+|-/g` Mind the space after the initial `/`.